# What happened to TituRel?

Tags: mathematical-software

TituRel is a language developed in conjunction with the book Relational Mathematics by Gunther Schmidt from Universität der Bundeswehr München.

My problem is that I can't find any info related to downloading this software.

Do you know where the TituRel software can be downloaded from? The [home page](https://titurel.org/TituRel/indexTituRel.html) does not seem to show any download links.

Taken directly from the [home page](https://titurel.org/TituRel/indexTituRel.html):
*TituRel is a software system to work with relations. It offers various tools written in the functional programming language Haskell allowing to*

- *input/output relations from/to several forms of delivery*
- *formulate relational terms to be applied to such relations in a newly developed multilevel relational reference language*
- *analyze relations, decompose, permute, and partition them so as to obtain better information*
- *support proofs of relation-algebraic theorems with transformation capabilities and TeX printing*
- *switch between point-free form and component form with system support*
- *generate programs for the RelView system*

Comment: This seems obviously on-topic for this site, so I don't understand the close votes or downvote.  The question could be improved, though: You could offer more details of what Titurel is, and it makes more sense to ask a more general question like "What happened to Titurel?"

Comment: @arsmath, thanks for your input, the post was edited to reflect your suggestions

Comment: Have you tried contacting Gunther Schmidt directly, or one of his co-authors on work with TituRel, e.g. Wolfram Kahl?  Their contact details are on their homepages, https://www.unibw.de/inf2/personen/professoren/schmidt , http://www.cas.mcmaster.ca/~kahl/  (Schmidt seems to be the main person, but co-authors could be a fallback if Schmidt doesn’t respond.)

Comment: @Peter, thanks for the suggestion, i just contacted professor Schmidt and now waiting for an answer, i'll post back if i receive any info

Comment: I received a reply from professor Schmidt, unfortunately TituRel is not available as a downloadable software due to not much interest from outside world.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [swMATH description](https://www.swmath.org/software/8501) says that: ***TituRel*** has a common source with the widely known **RelView**. It is far less efficient, strictly functional, and visualization-oriented. A formal deployment has not yet taken place; it exists as a one-man endeavour.

So I guess this explains why the software is not publicly available. The alternative ***RelView*** can be downloaded from [here.](https://www.informatik.uni-kiel.de/~progsys/relview/)

Answer (score 3):

You might also want to check out Ampersand, which applies relational methods to information systems:

Code: https://github.com/AmpersandTarski/Ampersand

Documentation: https://ampersandtarski.github.io/